# How to annotate python function that return single outcome but in different type conditionally?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def foo(x: int, y: int) -> sth:
    if x > 0:
        return x + y
    else:
        return None
```

`x + y` is `int` but `None` is `bool`

How to annotate the `sth` in the declaration?
Thank you.

Comment: By the way `None` is not `bool`. It's just `None`... But also, if your function returns an `int`, it might be better to return `0` instead of `None`, for consistency

Comment: @Tomerikoo it does answer my question! Thanks

Comment: Please mark the question as duplicate (or delete it) if that answered your question